# Semaphore Operations

Tags: c, semaphore

I was reading a text on semaphores and their operations. The author emphasized that the `wait()` and `post()` operations of semaphores should be executed atomically, otherwise mutual exclusion of the threads may be violated. Can anybody, please explain to me what he means? I am new to multi-threading by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation of context switch, where a task / process is replaced by another by the kernel is asynchronous  and undeterministic.

Let's examine the following code:

```
x++;
```

seems simple, hah ?
However this code is prone to synchronization errors, if x is shared among different tasks / process.

To understand that, you must understand the concept of atomic operation.

Atomic operation are instructions that the processor can execute on a single clock.
It usually involves reading a register, writing a register, etc.

back to the code example:
What actually happens behind the scenes (assembly) when incrementing a variable is
that the cpu reads the value of the variable into a register.
then, it increments it.
and then it saves it back to the original place it tool it from (memory).

As you can see, a simple operation like this involves 3 cpu steps.
context switch can occur between these 3 steps.

Let's take an example of two threads that needs to increment the same variable x.

Let's examine the pseudo assembly code of an imaginary (yet possible) scenario

1. read the value to register (thread 1)
2. increment the value (thread 1)
   CONTEXT SWITCH
3. read the value to register (thread 2)
4. increment the value (thread 2)
5. save the value (thread 2)
   CONTEXT SWITCH
6. save the value (thread 1)

if x was 3, it appears that it needs to be 5 now, but it will be 4.

Now, let's refer to your original question.
a semaphore / mutex is actually a variable.
and when a process wants to to take it it increments it.

Comment: You might want to note that the context switch will save a thread's registers, and restore them again when it is run again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `wait()` and `post()` operations on semaphore are not executed atomically mutual execution of thread can be violated.

For example, consider a semaphore with value `S = 1` and processes `P1` and `P2` try to to execute `wait()` simultaneously as below,

At time `T0`, `T1` process `P1`, `P2` finds the value of semaphore as `S = 1` respectively followed by decrementing the semaphore to acquire the lock and enter the critical section simultaneously violating the mutual execution of threads.

To employ atomicity between `wait()` and `post()` [spin-locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) until the lock is obtained is advised.

Comment: First, it's not atomicity between `wait()` and `post()` that's important, but rather between `wait()` in one process or one CPU, and `wait()` in another; or `post()` in one process or one CPU and `post()` in another.  Also, a spin-lock is really just a busy-wait form of semaphore, and so it's obviously not appropriate for a single-CPU system unless some form of interrupt can allow the resource holder to relinquish it. The level of atomicity required depends on what level (kernel or user) these operations are implemented at.